# ProgressBar.Value = <> not updating util the end

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get my progress bar to update once each of my functions is complete. I need a way for it to display on the progress bar at 25% after function 1, 50% after function 2, 75% after function 3, and 100% after function 4. Right now it is just updates the whole progress bar at the very end all at once to 100%.

```
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
VModel.ssdUtility.Func1();
Progress1.Value = 25;

VModel.ssdUtility.Func2();
Progress1.Value = 50;

VModel.ssdUtility.Func3();
Progress1.Value = 75;

VModel.ssdUtility.Func4();
Progress1.Value = 100;
}
else return;
```

Comment: Is there code in the RunWorkerCompleted handler?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're probably running your methods in the same thread as the UI, so the UI gets frozen until all your processing is done. You should run these methods in another thread.